Insert Deleted into #temp table to get the count of deleted records in a while loop deleting in batches
I am trying to get the count of deleted records in a script where I am deleting rows from many tables in order to purge data because of insufficient space on disk.
The delete is happening in batches of 500 as the table contains millions of records
 WHILE (1 = 1)
  BEGIN

 SELECT * INTO #tempHistTable1 FROM DatabaseABC..HistTable1 WHERE 0=1
 
 DELETE DatabaseABC..HistTable1
 OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO #tempHistTable1
   WHERE  ExtractionDate < ='2016-12-31'

 Select @qry = 'Select ''Total Number of records deleted from HistTable1 = '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), COUNT(1)) from #tempHistTable1 '

       ---- Send the e-mail Total Count of Deleted Records
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
           @recipients = 'first.lastname@abc.com',
           @query = @qry,
           @subject = 'Records Deleted in HistTable1'

 IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BREAK;

  END

 WHILE (1 = 1)

 BEGIN
 SELECT * INTO #tempHistTable2 FROM DatabaseABC..HistTable2 WHERE 0=1
 
 DELETE DatabaseABC..HistTable2
 OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO #tempHistTable2
   WHERE  ExtractionDate < ='2016-12-31'

      Select @qry = 'Select ''Total Number of records deleted from HistTable2 = '' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), COUNT(1)) from #tempHistTable2 '

       ---- Send the e-mail Total Count of Deleted Records
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
           @recipients = 'first.lastname@abc.com',
           @query = @qry,
           @subject = 'Records Deleted in HistTable2'

 IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BREAK;
  
END

How can achieve that > send the count of records deleted? With the above code I am getting the error that the #temp table already exists (I know the reason that is because when the while loop executes the next batch - the #temp table is already there ). But how can I get the total count of deleted records and then send it in email?

Just create your temp table in advance, and insert into it, rather than selecting into it.

Would sp_send_dbmail even be able to access the #tempHistTable1 table created in the current spid's context? I expect you'll get the vague and unhelpful error: Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

You should create (select * info #temp....) the temp table outside of the while loop

If the only purpose of the temp table is to get the rowcount then don't bother. Just do the delete and then assign @@rowcount to a variable in the next statement and use that variable's value - do you really want to send an email for every batch of 500 rows deleted though?

Currently your IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 is broken as the check is not immediately after the DELETE and it will be reset BTW

Your script have some issues, how about this version:
DECLARE @count INT
,   @totalcount INT
,   @qry NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  *
INTO    #tempHistTable1
FROM    DatabaseABC..HistTable1
WHERE   0=1

SET @totalcount = 0
 
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP(500) DatabaseABC..HistTable1
    OUTPUT  DELETED.*
    INTO    #tempHistTable1
    WHERE   ExtractionDate < ='2016-12-31'
    --
    SET @count = @@ROWCOUNT
    
    IF @count = 0
        BREAK;

    SET @totalcount = @totalcount + @count

    SELECT  @qry = 'Select ''Total Number of records deleted from HistTable1 = ' + CAST(@totalcount AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ''''

       ---- Send the e-mail Total Count of Deleted Records
    EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
           @recipients = 'first.lastname@abc.com',
           @query = @qry,
           @subject = 'Records Deleted in HistTable1'

END

SELECT  *
INTO    #tempHistTable2
FROM    DatabaseABC..HistTable2
WHERE   0=1

SET @totalcount = 0
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
 
    DELETE  TOP(500) DatabaseABC..HistTable2
    OUTPUT  DELETED.*
    INTO    #tempHistTable2
    WHERE   ExtractionDate < ='2016-12-31'
    --
    SET @count = @@ROWCOUNT
    
    IF @count = 0
        BREAK;

    SET @totalcount = @totalcount + @count

    SELECT  @qry = 'Select ''Total Number of records deleted from HistTable2 = ' + CAST(@totalcount AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ''''
     ---- Send the e-mail Total Count of Deleted Records
    EXEC    msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
           @recipients = 'first.lastname@abc.com',
           @query = @qry,
           @subject = 'Records Deleted in HistTable2'
 
END


This one actually batches in 500 rows
Properly jumps out on finish line

If you don't need to keep the old rows, you can remove the whole SELECT INTO / OUTPUT DELETED thing, it should speed up your execution.

Thanks @Siggermannen. Now I know where I was making mistake. But wouldn't this code send email for every batch of 500? Shouldn't the sp_send_dbmail code be outside the while loops?

I was following your original script and thought you wanted to email progressively. But yes, if you want to send it only once, you just move it out
